# Microsoft graph: create call (or meeting) as a third party

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a Java application that I'm refactoring to work with Microsoft Teams (hard requirement). Essentially, people find other people online based on some business criteria and they can call each other if interested. What I'm doing so far is using the Microsoft Graph api like this:

```
MicrosoftGraphAuth authProvider = new MicrosoftGraphAuth();
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider.getTokenCredAuthProvider()).buildClient();

        OnlineMeeting onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting();

        OnlineMeeting result = graphClient.users("<my_id>").onlineMeetings()
            .buildRequest()
            .post(onlineMeeting);
```

This seems a bit silly to me. Why do I have to add my user id as a third party? Is there some way to create a call? How can they return to my website on exiting the meeting? Also, is there some way to decide who is the meeting organizer based on the url that he connects with? Thank you.